# Creating tab and loading screen for the same in qml

Tags: qt, qml, tabbar

i am trying to create a tab and then load respective screen for that but when i am trying to place some components inside tab screen not able to achieve that. How is this possible?

Below is the code snippet for the tab created.
Need suggestion for how to create a respective screen for each tab dynamically.

```
    Rectangle
{
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height

    property variant tabname: ["tab1","tab2","tab3"]
    property variant tabScreen: ["Screen1","Screen2", "Screen3"]

    function setTabName(name)
    {
        tabname = name
    }

    function setTabScreen(screen)
    {
        tabScreen = screen
    }

    TabBar
    {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width

        Repeater
        {
            model: tabname.length
            TabButton
            {
                text: tabname[index]
            }
        }
    }

    StackLayout
    {
        id: stacklyt
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        anchors.top: bar.bottom

        Repeater
        {
            model: tabScreen.length
            Rectangle
            {
                id: tabRect
                color: "gray"
                Layout.preferredWidth: 10
                Layout.preferredHeight: 20

                Text {
                    id: name
                    text: tabScreen[index]
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }


    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        setTabName(tabname)
        setTabScreen(tabScreen)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` property to `Rectangle`, and whereever you refer to `tabName` or `tabScreen` use this `id`:

```
Rectangle
{
    id: rect
    ...
    property variant tabName: ["tab1","tab2","tab3"]
    property variant tabScreen: ["Screen1","Screen2", "Screen3"]

    TabBar
    {
        ...
        Repeater
        {
            model: rect.tabName
            TabButton
            {
                text: rect.tabName[index]
            }
        }
    }

    StackLayout
    {
        ...

        Repeater
        {
            model: rect.tabScreen
            Rectangle
            {
                ...

                Text {
                    id: name
                    text: rect.tabScreen[index]
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, property `model` should be proper collection, not a length of collection (see code). Also, what for are `setTabName` and `setTabScreen` functions? You don't need them to reach your target, as far as I understand your question.